# after converting html5canvas into image it is not getting inserted as image in html

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to convert html5canvas into an image and want to load that image in page again but it's not working.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  
  }

  function myFunction() {
    var v = document.getElementById("mTextArea").value;
    document.getElementById("wow").innerHTML = v;

    html2canvas(document.getElementById("imagewrap"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        canvas.className = "html2canvas";
        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");<====
        document.getElementById("img_prev").innerHTML = image;<====
      },
      useCORS: true
    });
  }
```

Please suggest what am I suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canvas.toDataURL` will result to an image. To insert an image into HTML the `innerHTML` is not the correct way. You should set that image as the source of a `<img>` tag. Assuming that **img_prev** is a `<img>` tag then:

```
    document.getElementById("img_prev").src= image;
```